# Filebeat kafka output use filename as key

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

I want to use filebeat 5.4.0 to ship log to kafka. My logs are all docker container logs, in `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/${container_name}.log`, or **soft link** in `/var/log/containers/${appname}-${container_name}.log`.

I want to save all app logs to one topic in kafka. And my requirements are:

1. Make sure the log from the same container go to the same partition
   in order.
2. The msg must contains the appname and the container_name where it comes out.

And I'm facing two problems.

1. How to get log from a soft link?
2. How to get the appname and container_name from the filename, and set to key of output.kafka?

Comment: I know how to get log from symlink now. set `symlinks: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beats are supposed to be lightweight, if you want to do more filtering then that is what logstash is for. You can use `filebeats+logstash+kafka`. Before sending to kafka, use logstash's split filter.
Also you can use 'type' property in filebeats to map the log paths like below
...
paths:

- `"/var/log/container/${appname}-${container_name}"`

  document_type: log
  output.kafka:
      ...
      key:'%{[type]}'
  ...

Comment: so，filebeat cannot do it? Thanks Vimal